# How do I pass a list of cookies to Wfuzz?

Tags: fuzzing

I know that you can pass cookies in Wfuzz by using multiple -b parameters like so: `wfuzz -w /path/to/wordlist -b cookie1=foo -b cookie2=bar http://example.com/FUZZ`

but I am wondering if you can pass a *list* of cookies, instead of doing them one by one, which takes forever and is ineffecient. I have looked everywhere for an answer it seems but I can't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "list" in this case, but I'm assuming you mean you want to pass them as a single argument instead of having to specify multiple `-b` arguments.

Of course, cookies are just sent in an HTTP header, and `-b` is provided for convenience as to not require you to craft the header manually.

However, check out the [wfuzz man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/wfuzz.1.html):

> -H headers
>
> ```
> Use headers (ex:"Host:www.mysite.com,Cookie:id=1312321&user=FUZZ"). Repeat option for various headers.
> ```

So, you should be able to pass a cookie header with a list of cookies.

Comment: Yes I read before that you can just make your own headers. I was hoping there was a way to just save the cookies to a cookie jar, but I guess thats not a feature in wfuzz. Thanks for  the answer.

Answer (score 0):

*wfuzz* ***does*** provide session cookie functionality comparable to *curl*'s cookie jar functionality.
At the core, it's *wfuzz*' *introspection* functionality and the ***wfuzzp*** type payload that can be used from the *preceding* request in an HTTP session.

There's a detailed explanation of how it is done on the github page of a framework called *metahttp* (which can be used as a convenience wrapper that generates *wfuzz* commands), see https://github.com/1LAB9fJYvmL9FUQREiUc2Rz7weVCm42qBs/metahttp/blob/master/ADVANCED.md 

Basically, the scenario has a request save its corresponding HTTP response as an object file using the `--oF WFUZZP1` switch, which the subsequent request introspects with the `-z wfuzzp,WFUZZP1` directive which associates the payload with the placeholder *FUZZ* (or FUZ2Z,FUZ3Z, respectively).
Based on that, *wfuzz* can set the cookies of the subsequent HTTP request using a switch such as `-b 'cookieXYZ=FUZZ[r.cookies.response.cookieXYZ]'`